# Select checkboxes in a pdf with Python (PyPDF2)

Tags: python, pdf, checkbox, pypdf

I'm trying to automate filling this PDF:
https://www.sepe.es/SiteSepe/contenidos/empresas/contratos_trabajo/asistente/pdf/temporal/Temporal.pdf
(decrypt it with ilovepdf).

I have no problem with the text, but with the checkboxes there is no way. Many /Btn have /Kids those /kids are other checkboxes that appear as "indirectObject". Also, normal checkboxes I can't select/modify in this pdf (examples bellow)

### Code

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject
from collections import OrderedDict

def set_need_appearances_writer(writer: PdfFileWriter):
    # See 12.7.2 and 7.7.2 for more information: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        # get the AcroForm tree
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)
            })

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
        # del writer._root_object["/AcroForm"]['NeedAppearances']
        return writer

    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))
        return writer

reader = PdfFileReader("TEMPORAL COMPLETO12 de mayo_unlocked.pdf")
writer = PdfFileWriter()

set_need_appearances_writer(writer)

page = reader.pages[0]

writer.addPage(page)

#Texto4 works, but not the checkboxes
writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(
    writer.getPage(0), {'BOTON_TIPOJORNADA': '/1',
                        'BOTON_JORN': '/S',
                        'Texto4': 'Texto4'
                        }
)
with open("filled-out.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)
reader.stream.close()
```

If I modified the pdf manually and read the fields...:

```
reader.getFields()

OUTPUT (one checkbox selected):
[...]

'BOTON_JORN': {'/FT': '/Btn',
  '/Kids': [IndirectObject(160, 0),
   IndirectObject(162, 0),
   IndirectObject(167, 0),
   IndirectObject(172, 0)],
  '/T': 'BOTON_JORN',
  '/Ff': 49152,
  '/V': '/S'},

OUTPUT (another checkbox selected):
[...]

'BOTON_JORN': {'/FT': '/Btn',
  '/Kids': [IndirectObject(160, 0),
   IndirectObject(162, 0),
   IndirectObject(167, 0),
   IndirectObject(172, 0)],
  '/T': 'BOTON_JORN',
  '/Ff': 49152,
  '/V': '/D'},
```

Another checkbox, with NO /kids but I can't select/modify is:
'TEXTOCasilla de verificación25' when selected has the value '/S#ED'

```
'TEXTOCasilla de verificación25': {'/FT': '/Btn',
  '/T': 'TEXTOCasilla de verificación25',
  '/V': '/S#ED'},
```

**Any tip will be great**

Answer (score 0):

Always confused why programmers need to destroy form templates, it is a blank canvas to be populated **without a program** only a viewer/printer so you fill the FDF and opening the FDF will automatically write the PDF, with all the new field entry values, including buttons, check boxes or other selections.

```
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF <<
/F (TEMPORAL COMPLETO12 de mayo.pdf)
/Fields [<<
/T (TEXTO Casilla de verificación 480)
/V /Off
>> <<
/T (TEXTO Casilla de verificación 481)
/V /Off
>> <<
/T (TEXTO20369)
/V /Off
>> <<
/T (TEXTOCasilla de verificación106666)
/V /Off
...
<<
/T (TEXTOCasilla de verificación95555)
/V /Off
>> <<
/T (Texto4)
```

***/V (My Inputted value for the PDF)***

```
>> <<
/T (Textocasilla de verificación3)
/V /Off
>> <<
/T (Textocasilla de verificación30)
/V /Off
>>]
/ID [<25F5DFD17199935FF41213A08FEAFF84> <9D8212B1DE099CB9D6BC87991799EBC3>]
/UF (TEMPORAL COMPLETO12 de mayo.pdf)
>>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

[image]

There are many libraries including Python ones to export the FDF for populating via server or command line (even manual edit via MS NotePad) or Find and Replace a text value. For a powerful example see https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/py/FDFTest/ but on github a search of `FDF PDF` should throw up dozens.

Note the sample above will need the export restriction over-ruled.

Once you write or edit the text FDF entries, then simply opening the FDF will auto populate the associated blank template.pdf, even if it was restricted.

Here opening data file I need to confirm its allowed

[image]

But we can see the data I write (in this case the field name), has been imported

[image]

**Note:-** when importing not every field needs to be added, but you do need to fill all fields as required for a resave.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.
I need to do it with python because this program will run in a server automatically. What are you using? Whats your code?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I can see any exportable form. What are you using? Can you explain to me like I'm where dumb? :)

Ok, I will search for a fdf...