# Can I use a Batch script to fill form fields in a PDF document?

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I have a form field fillable PDF that I'd like to fill using a batch script, I can't use JavaScript which seems to be the preferred solution. Is this something that can be done through a batch script?

The fields can be tabbed through and assuming the alt text of a field is its name, I have those as well, though at least 1 field appears to be unnamed.

Ideally I'd like to fill multiple specific fields with variables that I can programmatically generate and then save the PDF as a new file.

Comment: Batch can't communicate with other applications. You need another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can

[image]

Result

[image]

There are potential restrictions using Acrobat, and its better to use their API, however, I prefer PDFXedit from Tracker, which will also respond better to that same FDF form File especially allowing for saving, import export etc.

[image]

You dont need to build the same way I did but its as complex or as simple as  use a header string

```
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF <<
/F (AcroForm.pdf)
/Fields [<<
```

and a trailer string, ideally change the number as a valid ID <16x2> <16x2>

```
>>]
/ID [<31323334353637383940414243444546> <31323334353637383940414243444546>]
/UF (AcroForm.pdf)
>>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

The Field data is a /Tag and /Value pair and each must be separated by >> <<
and (literal text) is bracketed. There are possibilities to use bitmaps as text, and other embedment's, but that's way beyond this Proof Of Concept.

```
/T (CheckBox1)/V /On
>> <<
/T (TestTextBox)/V (The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy form.)
```

For a more complex case see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547163/10802527

Now to complete the process you need to save the file with a new name which will depend on your choice of FDF application. The top three apps for windows can all be driven by batch file keyboard macros, since we have avoided any need for mouse selection of fields. For PDFXchange it would start like `ALT+F+A+B+"Filepath\name.pdf"`

Using vanilla cmd we can write a vbs script or easier use [sendkeys.exe](http://cpap.com.br/orlando/SendKeysMore.asp) to run the focused sequence (again beyond the scope of a short answer) but for [Xchange](https://www.tracker-software.com/search?query=fdf) (/close[:[mode=]save|discard|ask]) and I think [Foxit](https://kb.foxitsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042671711-Parameters-for-Opening-PDF-Files-with-a-command) they have their own command line /api methods.

Preferably the commands should be done via piped DDE as easier to say open FDF and close PDF but those methods seem to generally be depreciated and of the three only Acrobat may still use them.

Comment: Thank you! I know stack doesn't like my question but clearly you managed an answer!